# SQL - Better two queries instead of one big one

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, performance

I am working on a C# application, which loads data from a MS SQL 2008 or 2008 R2 database. The table looks something like this:

```
ID | binary_data | Timestamp
```

I need to get only the last entry and only the binary data. Entries to this table are added irregular from another program, so I have no way of knowing if there is a new entry.
Which version is better (performance etc.) and why?

```
//Always a query, which might not be needed
public void ProcessData()
{
    byte[] data = "query code get latest binary data from db"
}
```

vs

```
//Always a smaller check-query, and sometimes two queries
public void ProcessData()
{
    DateTime timestapm = "query code get latest timestamp from db"
    if(timestamp > old_timestamp)
      data = "query code get latest binary data from db"
}
```

The binary_data field size will be around 30kB. The function "ProcessData" will be called several times per minutes, but sometimes can be called every 1-2 seconds. This is only a small part of a bigger program with lots of threading/database access, so I want to the "lightest" solution. Thanks.

Comment: Try testing it out yourself with your data and use case...?

Comment: depends on how often that irregular update is and how large the binary data is, but I'd say unless it's close to as often as you're checking you're better off going with the 2 query solution.

Comment: IMO, it would depend n the ration of new entries of the binary data. but why can't you always respond timestamp, Data = NULL if there is nothing new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, you can have both:

```
SELECT TOP 1 binary_data
  FROM myTable
 WHERE Timestamp > @last_timestamp
 ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

If there is a no record newer than `@last_timestamp`, no record will be returned and, thus, no data transmission takes place (= fast). If there are new records, the binary data of the newest is returned immediately (= no need for a second query).

Comment: @SamLeach: If multiple records have been added since `@last_timestamp`, the TOP 1/ORDER BY-combination ensures that only the last one will be returned.

Comment: Can't we assume that the top record will be the record with the most recent timestamp? I guess we shouldn't assume. ;)

Comment: @SamLeach: That's what the ORDER BY is for! It ensures that the records are sorted in order of decreasing timestamp. Thus, the top one will *always* be the one with the largest (= most recent) timestamp.

Comment: My argument is that, by the nature of a timestamp, they will already be chronologically ordered in the table.

Comment: @SamLeach: As far as I know, the "natural" ordering of a table depends on the clustered index of the table, which is *probably* `ID` in this case, but we don't know for sure. The ORDER BY ensures that we get the order we need for the TOP 1 to return the "correct" record.

Comment: you are assuming the records get inserted in a temporally sequential manner.

Comment: you are both right, the timestamp could be a problem, it should always be UtcNow and in the right order, anyway I can sort by the index. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you perform tests using both methods as the answer would depend on your usages. Simulate some expected behaviour.

I would say though, that you are probably okay to just do the first query. Do what works. Don't prematurely optimise, if the single query is too slow, try your second *two-query* approach.

Answer (score 1):

Two-step approach is more efficient from overall workload of system point of view:

1. Get informed that you need to query new data
2. Query new data

There are several ways to implement this approach. Here are a pair of them.

1. [Using Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110%28SQL.100%29.aspx) which is built-in functionality of SQL Server supported in .NET.
2. Using implied method of getting informed of database table update, e.g. one described in [this article at SQL Authority blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better path is a storedprocedure that keeps the logic inside the database, Something with an output parameter with the data required and a return value like a TRUE/FALSE to signal the presence of new data